# Run specific python version that is not in PATH

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6

I am working with a remote machine that I am not administrator in it.
This machine has python 2.6.5 installed and also it appears in PATH.

After I asked they installed in the machine also python 2.7.9, but they refuse to add it to PATH.

is there a way I can execute a script from the command line using the newer version?

Comment: You can change the PATH yourself by editing your user's start-up file.  Which file that should be depends on the shell you are using.  You don't need an administrator for that, and it will only affect your user name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the full path to where the python executable is located.

Instead of doing:

```
python C:\path\to\your\py\file
```

you do:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\path\to\your\py\file
```

with the file path placed in quotes if necessary:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:\path\to\your\py\file"
```